# How belongsTo works with mutiple hasMany in contain cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I need the users for with given property id e.g.`Property.id = $id`

I want to build this query.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.address1, p.address2, p.address3, p.postcode,
               u.email, u.fullname
               c.company_name, 
               tc.created,
               tn.active
        FROM property AS p
        LEFT JOIN tenancy AS tc ON tc.property_id = p.id 
        LEFT JOIN tenant AS tn ON tn.tenancy_id = tc.id 
        LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = tn.user_id 
        WHERE p.id = $id
            AND p.active = 1
            AND tc.active = 1
            AND tn.active = 1
            AND u.active = 1
        ";
```

Here is my associations:

```
// Tenants
class TenantTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('tenant');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Tenancies', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tenancy_id',
        'className' => 'tenancy',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);


// Users
class UsersTable extends Table
{

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('name');

    $this->hasMany('Tenants', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'foreignKey' => 'tenants'
    ]);
}


// Tenancies
class TenancyTable extends Table
{

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('tenancy');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Properies', [
        'foreignKey' => 'property_id',
        'className' => 'property'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Company', [
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id'
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('Tenant', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tenancy_id',
        'className' => 'tenant'
    ]);


// Properties
class PropertyTable extends Table
{

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('property');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Company', [
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id'
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('Tenancies', [
        'foreignKey' => 'property_id',
        'className' => 'tenancy'
    ]);
}
```

I can get the hasMany associations but when it comes to get belongsTo for Users it tells me Tenants is not associated with Users. How ever the associations are set and they are correct. I am running the following ORM from PropertyTable.

```
$query = $this->find()
            ->select([ 
                'Property.id', 'Property.company_id', 'Property.address1', 'Property.address2', 'Property.address3','Property.postcode',
                'Tenancies.id', 'Tenancies.property_id', 'Tenancies.created', 'Tenancies.stage', 'Tenancies.landlord_offer_sent',
                'Company.id', 'Company.company_name',
                'Tenants.id', 'Tenants.user_id', 'Tenants.stage', 
                'Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.fullname'
            ])
            ->where(['Property.id' => $id])
            ->contain(['Company', 'Tenancies'])
            ->leftJoinWith('Tenancies', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                return $query->where([
                    'Tenancies.active' => 1,
                ]);
            })
            ->contain(['Tenancies.Tenants'])
            ->leftJoinWith('Tenancies.Tenants', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                return $query->where([
                    'Tenants.active' => 1,
                ]);
            }) 
 /*======= The problem starts from here  =========*/        
            ->contain(['Tenancies.Tenants.Users'])
            ->leftJoinWith('Tenancies.Tenants.Users', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                return $query->where([
                    'Users.active' => 1,
                ]);
            });
```

Any help pelase

Comment: Just because you think the associations are correct, that doesn't mean that this has to be true. They may be correct, that may be not, people here can't tell without seeing them. In the world of programming, words aren't worth too much, code is what's important, so please, _always_ include all relevant code! Also please share your debugging attempts (like have you tried removing other containments/joins? Does containing/joining in users via the tenants table fail too? etc...). And last but not least, please always mention your exact CakePHP version.

Comment: Thank you mate. Sure I am gonna update the answer

Comment: @ndm The associations are updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to what you have provided us, you have the following relationships:

> Properties hasMany Tenancies hasMany Tenants belongsTo Users
>   Properties belongsTo Companies

Assuming you have that set up in your Table Classes, you can use joins with contains similar to how you did it above:

```
public function getExample($id) {
    return $this->find()
    ->contain([
        'Company' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['id', 'company_name'])
                ->where(['Company.active = 1']);
        },
        'Tenancies' => function($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['Tenancies.id','Tenancies.property_id','Tenancies.created',
                    'Tenancies.stage','Tenancies.landlord_offer_sent',
                    'Tenants.id','Tenants.stage', 'Tenants.user_id', 'Tenants.tenancy_id',
                    'Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.fullname'
                ])->leftJoin(['Tenants' => 'tenant'],[
                    'Tenants.tenancy_id = Tenancies.id'
                ])->leftJoin(['Users' => 'users'],[
                    'Users.id = Tenants.user_id'
                ])
                ->where([
                    'Tenancies.active = 1',
                    'Tenants.active = 1',
                    'Users.active = 1',
                ]);
        }
    ])
    ->where(['Property.active = 1', 'Property.id' => $id])
    ->toArray();
}
```

Comment: I edited this because there was a small error with the join type. It should now work with the left joins :)

Comment: Thank you mate you are star. I've done a bit of update on the query. it's is working like charme now

Comment: To comply with CakePHP naming standards, you should keep your relation names plural. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Chris, you could edit your answer to show that. @Fury - you should leave the code edit to the post author.

Comment: @chrisShick I haven't created those tables just getting data and it's a pain because it is not plural.